# ORACLE SQL Total Cost of a Customer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have three related tables "customers", "orders", "orderdetails"

***-"customers" has these columns:***

```
CUSTOMERID, COMPANYNAME, CONTACTNAME, 
CONTACTTITLE, ADDRESS, CITY, REGION, 
POSTALCODE, COUNTRY, PHONE, FAX
```

***-"orders" has these columns:***

```
ORDERID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID,
 TERRITORYID, ORDERDATE, REQUIREDDATE,
 SHIPPEDDATE, SHIPVIA, FREIGHT, SHIPNAME,
 SHIPADDRESS, SHIPCITY, SHIPREGION,
 SHIPPOSTALCODE, SHIPCOUNTRY
```

***-"orderdetails" has these columns:***

```
ORDERID, PRODUCTID, UNITPRICE, QUANTITY, DISCOUNT
```

**I have to make a query where I get the total expense with this formula (unitprice*quantity*(1-discount) of a client called ASHRAM, that name is the abbreviation that appears in customerid**

**I have tried to do this:**

```
SELECT customerid, COST (unitprice*quantity*(1-discount))
FROM CUSTOMERS JOIN orders ON customers.customerid=orders.customerid
JOIN orderdetails ON orders.orderid=orderdetails.orderid
WHERE customerid='ASHRAM';
```

But oracle tells me this: "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: you have two tables with the column customerid, so selrct one and use the clumn with its table name

Comment: COST (unitprice*quantity*(1-discount))   what does it mean?

Comment: It is difficult to explain it without images, but in the orderdetails table it has an orderid that identifies it with the price of that purchase, quantity purchased, discount, etc.

So, it is supposed to take all the orders that have the customerid "ASHRAM" do that operation (unitprice*quantity*(1-discount) for each purchase and add everything.

I have no idea where to start doing all that.

Comment: SELECT C.customerid, SUM(DET.unitprice*DET.quantity*(1-DET.discount))
FROM CUSTOMERS C JOIN orders ORD ON C.customerid=ORD.customerid
JOIN orderdetails DET ON ORD.orderid=DET.orderid
WHERE customerid='ASHRAM';

Comment: Oracle tells me this again: "column ambiguously defined" :(

Comment: It's also not going to let me use SUM because not a single-group group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  customers (customerid) as
  3    (select 'ASHRAM'     from dual union all
  4     select 'Littlefoot' from dual
  5    ),
  6  orders (orderid, customerid, orderdate) as
  7    (select 1, 'ASHRAM'    , date '2022-10-25' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'ASHRAM'    , date '2022-11-13' from dual union all
  9     select 3, 'Littlefoot', date '2023-01-13' from dual
 10    ),
 11  orderdetails (orderid, productid, unitprice, quantity, discount) as
 12    (select 1, 123, 10, 5, 0.10 from dual union all
 13     select 1, 456, 20, 2, 0.00 from dual union all
 14     select 2, 999,  5, 5, 0.20 from dual union all
 15     select 3, 757, 50, 1, 0.00 from dual
 16    )
```

Query joins all 3 tables on appropriate columns, aggregates prices for all products per all orders for ASHRAM and groups result per customer ID:

```
 17  select c.customerid,
 18    sum(d.unitprice * d.quantity * (1 - d.discount)) total
 19  from customers c join orders o on o.customerid = c.customerid
 20                   join orderdetails d on d.orderid = o.orderid
 21  where c.customerid = 'ASHRAM'
 22  group by c.customerid;

CUSTOMERID      TOTAL
---------- ----------
ASHRAM            105

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the tables by an alias if columns with the same name are existing in the query, otherwise oracle dont know witch column from which table you mean. This is also necessary on the where condition and on the select fields:

```
SELECT o.customerid, (s.unitprice * s.quantity * (1 - s.discount)) AS COST
FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN orders o ON c.customerid = o.customerid
JOIN orderdetails s ON o.orderid = s.orderid
WHERE o.customerid='ASHRAM';
```

Comment: Right now I get 10 rows and two columns, how can I get a single row and column with the total expense?

Comment: This should give you what you search: 

SELECT SUM(s.unitprice * s.quantity * (1 - s.discount)) AS COST
FROM CUSTOMERS c JOIN orders o ON c.customerid = o.customerid
JOIN orderdetails s ON o.orderid = s.orderid
WHERE o.customerid='ASHRAM';